# MobileFiirst IBM App Center not list iPad universal app in iPhone device

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst, mobilefirst-appcenter

I have a MobileFirst App for iPAD created using MobileFirst iPad environment. After build the app, in xCode we have changed the build setting from iPAD to Universal App. After uploading the iPA to IBM Application Center, it shows Device Family:iphone, iPad.

But while try to access the iPA from IBM app center client on iPhone. Its not listing this application.

MobileFirst Server, App Center, App Center client, Studio Version: 7.1.0.00-20151114-1616

Answer (score 2):

From your problem description I guess that you can get the application only when using iPad.
Please try to create 2 separates IPA files for iPad environment and iPhone environment (add these 2 environments in eclipse).

then, in the applicationDescriptor.xml you will have 2 different environments one for iPad and one for iPhone.

As far as I know you will need these two environments in order to download the application to iPad and iPhone.
Creating an iPad environment and change the build setting to universal will not work.
Please follow:

https://developer.ibm.com/mobilefirstplatform/documentation/getting-started-7-1/foundation/hello-world/your-first-hybrid-application/#addingEnvironments

https://developer.ibm.com/mobilefirstplatform/documentation/getting-started-7-1/foundation/moving-production/distributing-mobile-applications-with-application-center/